# Using " break " statement in " for loop " not working

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, break

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i;    // i wanted to print numbers each with difference of 2 up to 18

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)    
    {
        printf("the number we get is %d\n\n", i);    

        ++i;    

        if (i == 18)    
        {
            break;    
        }
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3M8.png)

I removed ++i; before if statement then it worked. but i couldn't understand why its not working with ++i. with ++i it prints upto 24 with difference of 2 ( which i get is due to i++ & ++i used )

Comment: sorry if questions format is wrong, while submitting it was showing error to indent code. i tried doing. thanks very much

Comment: Try moving the `printf` immediately before the `if`.  I think that may make it clearer why the `if` condition is never triggered but showing you what value `i` has at each test.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. Program output is text that can be copy/pasted.

Comment: The break never occurs because if (i == 18) always fails, because i is incremented twice during each loop. In every (i == 18) test i is an odd number. If you want to check only even numbers, use i += 2 instead of ++i as the third expression in the for loop (and drop the other ++i).

Answer (score 1):

The `i++` in `for` statement is executed after every loop.
So `i` will never be 18 in `if`.

Comment: To solve this issue, delete `++i` and change `i++` to `i+=2`. There is no reason to add i twice.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging:

You initalize `i` with `0` and increment it twice each iteration. The critical section is where you have your terminating condition:

```c
printf("the number we get is %d\n\n", i); // prints 18

++i;

if (i == 18) { // i will always be 19 here
```

This clearly misses the terminating condition.